# Use html2pdf from $this->renderpartial in Yii

Tags: php, yii, renderpartial, html2pdf

Can I do something like this:

```
$content = $this->renderpartial('DeedCertificate',array('deed'=>$deed,'cnt'=>$cnt));        
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('/var/www/myapp/images/example.pdf','F');
```

$html2pdf->Output when using $content = "hello"l works like a charm. 
Now I'm trying to pass the output of yii's renderpartial .. so it can become a pdf.. but my pdf is blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make [renderPartial to return](http://yiiapi.com/CController#renderPartial-detail) the `html generated` for you ,like this:

```
 $this->renderPartial('DeedCertificate' , array('data'=>$data) , true); // set this to true
```

Comment: I don't know that, I guess you could check that out yourself :D

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry for that!! I should check it out myself. And thanks for the quick response!